# hasClass + addClass not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below script is supposed to add a class (.active) to .global-header if .navigation.primary has a class of .active, but it doesn't seem to be working?

**JS**

```
if($(".navigation.primary").hasClass("active")) {
    $('.global-header').addClass('active');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="global-header">
    <div class="site-navigation">
        <div class="left-menu"></div>
        <div class="right-menu"></div>
    </div>
</header>

<nav class="navigation primary">Menu</nav>
```

Comment: Can you show the html code ?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your DOM too?

Comment: In what way does it not "*seem to be working?*" What's going wrong, what's not happening, what's happening that shouldn't happen, what error messages are being reported in your browser? How do you expect us to address this problem without knowing what the problem is, or what you expect to happen?

Comment: Have updated question. I expect the class of .active to be added to .global-header when .navigation.primary has a class of .active. Currently this isn't happening.

Comment: It is working: https://jsfiddle.net/3tdnnLnq/2/

Comment: what your console says? You're sure that Jquery is loaded?

Comment: are you sure that your `.navigation.primary` has class active? As I linked the jsFiddle, you can see thats a working code. Maybe you need to bind it to an event listener, if `navigaton.primary`  has not `active` class.

Comment: Hey @karacsi_maci, thanks for the advise. You were right, I needed to put this within an event listener:
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if ($(".navigation.primary").hasClass("active")) {
  $(".global-header").addClass("active");
 }
});

If you want to covert this into an answer, I will accept it. Cheers!

Comment: @dungey_140 I've added as an answer with your example. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, when you load the page, if the element with `navigation.primary` has no `active` class, but later, when an action happens will get the `active` then you need to add the event listener around your code to that event what triggers the class addition.

If the `navigation.primary` has the `active` when page loads, you need to add document ready:

```
$(function() { //when document is ready
    if($(".navigation.primary").hasClass("active")) {
       $('.global-header').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

or if an event happens, for example scroll the window:

```
$(function() { //when document is ready
   $(window).on('scroll', function() { //When scrolling
        if($(".navigation.primary").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.global-header').addClass('active');
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.navigation.primary` doesn't have an active class. So normally, `$(".navigation.primary").hasClass("active")` would evaluate to false.

```
<nav class="navigation primary">Menu</nav>
```

This should be:

```
<nav class="navigation primary active">Menu</nav>
```